# How would I use ::after to make an arrow on my button?

Tags: html, css

I can create a button with an arrow on the right side like this:

```css
.next-button {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background-color: #2399e5;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.next-point{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    
    border-left: 18px solid #2399e5;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button class="next-button" type="button">Next</button><div class="next-point"></div>
</div>
```

...but if I try to do it using ::after it just doesn't work out.  Here's how I've tried that:

```css
.next-button {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background-color: #2399e5;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.next-button::after{
    content: " ";
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    
    border-left: 18px solid #2399e5;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button class="next-button" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

I've fiddled around with this for a good while and clearly I don't fully understand how to use `::after`.  How would I accomplish the button look in my first snippet using `::after` instead of creating a separate div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pseudo element is a child of the `.next-button` element, so it's displayed inside the button. You can display it outside the button using absolute position, and a `right` equal to minus the pseudo element width (width = 36px -> right = -36px).

```css
.next-button {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #2399e5;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.next-button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: -36px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid #2399e5;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="next-button" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Another options is to position absolutely inside the element to the right, and use `translateX(100%)` to to push it outside.

```css
.next-button {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #2399e5;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.next-button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid #2399e5;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="next-button" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more elegant solution would be something alone those lines:

```css
.arrow-clip{
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 80% 0, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
      background-color: #2399e5;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0.2rem 2rem;
      border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="arrow-clip">Next</button>
```

If you would like to adjust the curves of your arrow you could google a simple clip generator, I think [this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) one is nice.